# Labels not showing

Tags: plotting

I want to plot a function ( I need the "Frame" and "ImagePadding" for later overlay of another graph):

`Plot[t^2, {t, 0, 5}, PlotStyle -> Blue, 
 Frame -> {True, True, True, False}, ImagePadding -> 25, 
 AxesLabel -> {"x label", "y label"}]`

but I cannot see the labels. I think that the labels are somewhere on the graph, but are not seen.
Also I want to add a legend in order that later I can use Overlay, but I cannot get the hang of it.
Do you have any tips?

Comment: Change "Axes" to "Frame" in AxesLabel.

Comment: Thanks! This worked for this example, but what if I have "Frame -> {False, False, False, True}"?

Comment: Then you do not have axes to put the labels on.

Comment: The axes aren't displayed if they are too near the frame. If you add lots of padding you will see them `PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[0.15]` but the plot looks silly.

Comment: You could use a full frame but make parts of it transparent? `Plot[t^2, {t, 0, 5}, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> (Style[#, Opacity[1]] & /@ {"x label", "y label"}), FrameStyle -> Opacity /@ {1, 0, 0, 1}]`

Comment: I want to add another plot with overlay function which has a y axis on the other side so the result would be a double y axis, but now only one of the two y axis would have a label

Comment: Found the solution to the other conundrum FrameLabel -> {{None, "Another label"}, {None, None}}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use a frame, axes are suppressed, so you need to give `Axes -> True`. Also you must provide some extra space along the left side and bottom of the plot.

```
Plot[t^2, {t, 0, 5},
 PlotStyle -> Blue,
 Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, True}},,
 PlotRangePadding -> {{.75, Automatic}, {5, Automatic}},
 Axes -> True,
 AxesLabel -> {"x label", "y label"}]
```

[image: plot]